# SQLSTATE[42S02] - from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

MYSQL triggers an SQLSTATE[42S02] error while processing a subquery with the table called through alias

`"UPDATE call_log AS c1 INNER JOIN call_log AS c2 ON c1.id = c2.id SET c1.end ='".$reponse."' WHERE c1.id = (SELECT MAX(c2.id) FROM (SELECT * from c2 WHERE c2.num =".$numero." ) derivee )";`

The desired outcome is to update the last matching line containing the $num variable in call_log table. As MYSQL prevents to do subqueries based on the same table I used aliases to refer to those tables as recommended here

[mySQL error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495373/mysql-error-1248-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

or here
[What is the error "Every derived table must have its own alias" in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/what-is-the-error-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-in-mysql)

The Error I get is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ERP.c2' doesn't exist'

Comment: Am I correct in saying you are joining the table to itself?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of your logic would all help.

Comment: I log into a database when the call starts and when it ends. The 'end' event happens through a eventlistener function. Of course I just want to update the field where the number called matches and where it is the last one.

Comment: Still the same error. My database is indeed called ERP. The table is call_log with 2 aliases c1 and c2. What I do not get is why MYSQL does not understand that c2 is an alias of call_log and not a base table ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the issue. I changed slightly the command to simplify the request.

```
$sql ="UPDATE call_log as c1 SET c1.end = '".$reponse."' WHERE c1.id = (SELECT MAX(derive.id) FROM (SELECT * FROM call_log c2) derive WHERE derive.num =".$numero.")";
```

The main difference is that I create an alias for the table itself as c2 **BUT** I also use the alias of the `(SELECT * FROM call_log c2) derive` where *derive* will be the alias to filter the subquery results !!

If it helps others....